# NoReverseMatch at /polls/ (django tutorial)

Tags: python, django

I have seen a few other questions about this on SO but they didn't solve my problem. I am running Django 1.8.5, Python 2.7.6.

I updated the root urls.py to

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
]
```

and polls/templates/polls/index.html to

```
{% if latest_question_list%}
   <ul>                                                                                           
   {% for question in latest_question_list %}                                                     
       <li><a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>   
   {% endfor %}                                                                                   
 </ul>                                                                                          
{% else %}                                                                                         
  <p>No polls are available.</p>                                                                 
{% endif %}
```

I get the error

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/
u'polls' is not a registered namespace.
```

I have tried restarting the development server as the other answers I have suggested, as well as including {% load url from future %} in the template code; neither has worked. Not sure what I am missing, my code matches the files in the tutorial.

Edit: 
polls/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'), 
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),]
```

Comment: Show the polls.urls code

Comment: What's the location of the root `urls.py` (occasionally new users create a second urls.py in the wrong place).

Comment: root urls.py is in mysite/urls.py, where mysite is the name of the root directory (not the nested mysite directory). So if I have this in a "development" directory with my other repos it is in Development/mysite/urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `ROOT_URLCONF` setting is `mysite.urls`, then the urls.py should be in the nested `mysite` directory, i.e. `mysite/mysite/urls.py`.